# R serialize function slow on some occasions

Tags: r, serialization, parallel-processing, shiny

I have a shiny application that takes user supplied data, adds weighted average to it (using user supplied weights) and then performs Monte Carlo simulation (this results in 1000 random series sampled from original data) on each series (column) in user data and on the added weighted average. The results of that are saved as a huge nested list. After that it calculates some stats on the resulting Monte Carlo series and draws charts and tables based on these stats. The application also allows changing the weights after it has been ran and then rerunning only weighted average part.

The sampling is done with lapply but the calculation of stats is done with parLapply. The clusters used in parLapply are stored in a global variable and reused throughout the application.

The problem is that when the user first runs the application then each column in provided file takes about 5 seconds to proccess (assuming 1000 simulations). On the second run however (rerunning weighted average with new weights) it takes about 30 seconds for weighted average alone.
I used Rprof to try and understand where the extra time comes from and I found that the function serialize is taking ~20 seconds on the second run while i took about half a second on the first run (this is per column in user supplied data).

I tried different things to resolve this. 
At first I thought this may be because data on second run is somewhat different (different structure, whatever) but when I sampled with a fixed seed and compared them the results with data from second run then they were identical (idendical())
Next I tried setting the variable that holds my data in a global object to NULL before assigning new values to it, that didnt help eithere.
I even tried using garbage collector inside the cluster before rerunning. Didnt help.

Below are the two Rprof results I got

LAST SERIES FROM FIRST RUN

```
$by.self
              self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
"unserialize"      3.38    79.72       3.38     79.72
"serialize"        0.50    11.79       0.50     11.79
"is.matrix"        0.16     3.77       0.16      3.77
"is.factor"        0.04     0.94       0.04      0.94
"<Anonymous>"      0.02     0.47       4.24    100.00
"rbind"            0.02     0.47       0.36      8.49
"%in%"             0.02     0.47       0.06      1.42
"match"            0.02     0.47       0.04      0.94
"attr"             0.02     0.47       0.02      0.47
"names"            0.02     0.47       0.02      0.47
"nargs"            0.02     0.47       0.02      0.47
"seq.int"          0.02     0.47       0.02      0.47

$by.total
                       total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
"<Anonymous>"                4.24    100.00      0.02     0.47
".Call"                      4.24    100.00      0.00     0.00
".func"                      4.24    100.00      0.00     0.00
"do.call"                    4.24    100.00      0.00     0.00
"doTryCatch"                 4.24    100.00      0.00     0.00
"eval"                       4.24    100.00      0.00     0.00
"evalq"                      4.24    100.00      0.00     0.00
"flushReact"                 4.24    100.00      0.00     0.00
"FUN"                        4.24    100.00      0.00     0.00
"func"                       4.24    100.00      0.00     0.00
"handler"                    4.24    100.00      0.00     0.00
"isolate"                    4.24    100.00      0.00     0.00
"lapply"                     4.24    100.00      0.00     0.00
"MCres"                      4.24    100.00      0.00     0.00
"Monte.Carlo"                4.24    100.00      0.00     0.00
"parSummary"                 4.24    100.00      0.00     0.00
"run"                        4.24    100.00      0.00     0.00
"runApp"                     4.24    100.00      0.00     0.00
"service"                    4.24    100.00      0.00     0.00
"serviceApp"                 4.24    100.00      0.00     0.00
"shinyCallingHandlers"       4.24    100.00      0.00     0.00
"try"                        4.24    100.00      0.00     0.00
"tryCatch"                   4.24    100.00      0.00     0.00
"tryCatchList"               4.24    100.00      0.00     0.00
"tryCatchOne"                4.24    100.00      0.00     0.00
"withCallingHandlers"        4.24    100.00      0.00     0.00
"withVisible"                4.24    100.00      0.00     0.00
"clusterApply"               3.88     91.51      0.00     0.00
"parLapply"                  3.88     91.51      0.00     0.00
"staticClusterApply"         3.88     91.51      0.00     0.00
"unserialize"                3.38     79.72      3.38    79.72
"recvData"                   3.38     79.72      0.00     0.00
"recvData.SOCKnode"          3.38     79.72      0.00     0.00
"serialize"                  0.50     11.79      0.50    11.79
"postNode"                   0.50     11.79      0.00     0.00
"sendCall"                   0.50     11.79      0.00     0.00
"sendData"                   0.50     11.79      0.00     0.00
"sendData.SOCKnode"          0.50     11.79      0.00     0.00
"rbind"                      0.36      8.49      0.02     0.47
"[["                         0.26      6.13      0.00     0.00
"[[.data.frame"              0.26      6.13      0.00     0.00
"is.matrix"                  0.16      3.77      0.16     3.77
"%in%"                       0.06      1.42      0.02     0.47
"is.factor"                  0.04      0.94      0.04     0.94
"match"                      0.04      0.94      0.02     0.47
"attr"                       0.02      0.47      0.02     0.47
"names"                      0.02      0.47      0.02     0.47
"nargs"                      0.02      0.47      0.02     0.47
"seq.int"                    0.02      0.47      0.02     0.47

$sample.interval
[1] 0.02

$sampling.time
[1] 4.24
```

SECOND RUN (ONE SERIES, WEIGHTED AVERAGE)

```
$by.self
                self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
"serialize"         27.82    88.32      27.82     88.32
"unserialize"        3.46    10.98       3.46     10.98
"rbind"              0.06     0.19       0.22      0.70
"match"              0.06     0.19       0.06      0.19
"<Anonymous>"        0.02     0.06      31.50    100.00
"[["                 0.02     0.06       0.14      0.44
"[[.data.frame"      0.02     0.06       0.12      0.38
"%in%"               0.02     0.06       0.08      0.25
"is.factor"          0.02     0.06       0.02      0.06

$by.total
                       total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
"<Anonymous>"               31.50    100.00      0.02     0.06
".Call"                     31.50    100.00      0.00     0.00
".func"                     31.50    100.00      0.00     0.00
"do.call"                   31.50    100.00      0.00     0.00
"doTryCatch"                31.50    100.00      0.00     0.00
"eval"                      31.50    100.00      0.00     0.00
"evalq"                     31.50    100.00      0.00     0.00
"flushReact"                31.50    100.00      0.00     0.00
"FUN"                       31.50    100.00      0.00     0.00
"func"                      31.50    100.00      0.00     0.00
"handler"                   31.50    100.00      0.00     0.00
"isolate"                   31.50    100.00      0.00     0.00
"lapply"                    31.50    100.00      0.00     0.00
"MCres"                     31.50    100.00      0.00     0.00
"Monte.Carlo"               31.50    100.00      0.00     0.00
"parSummary"                31.50    100.00      0.00     0.00
"run"                       31.50    100.00      0.00     0.00
"runApp"                    31.50    100.00      0.00     0.00
"service"                   31.50    100.00      0.00     0.00
"serviceApp"                31.50    100.00      0.00     0.00
"shinyCallingHandlers"      31.50    100.00      0.00     0.00
"try"                       31.50    100.00      0.00     0.00
"tryCatch"                  31.50    100.00      0.00     0.00
"tryCatchList"              31.50    100.00      0.00     0.00
"tryCatchOne"               31.50    100.00      0.00     0.00
"withCallingHandlers"       31.50    100.00      0.00     0.00
"withVisible"               31.50    100.00      0.00     0.00
"clusterApply"              31.28     99.30      0.00     0.00
"parLapply"                 31.28     99.30      0.00     0.00
"staticClusterApply"        31.28     99.30      0.00     0.00
"serialize"                 27.82     88.32     27.82    88.32
"postNode"                  27.82     88.32      0.00     0.00
"sendCall"                  27.82     88.32      0.00     0.00
"sendData"                  27.82     88.32      0.00     0.00
"sendData.SOCKnode"         27.82     88.32      0.00     0.00
"unserialize"                3.46     10.98      3.46    10.98
"recvData"                   3.46     10.98      0.00     0.00
"recvData.SOCKnode"          3.46     10.98      0.00     0.00
"rbind"                      0.22      0.70      0.06     0.19
"[["                         0.14      0.44      0.02     0.06
"[[.data.frame"              0.12      0.38      0.02     0.06
"%in%"                       0.08      0.25      0.02     0.06
"match"                      0.06      0.19      0.06     0.19
"is.factor"                  0.02      0.06      0.02     0.06

$sample.interval
[1] 0.02

$sampling.time
[1] 31.5
```

Does anyone know what may cause this?
Thanks in advance!

Edit (14.07.2014):

I checked with task manager like Steve suggested.

On the first run it seemed normal: 
master used CPU -> workers used CPU -> master used CPU -> workers used CPU -> ...
I guess this is because master hands over work, workers process and repeat. Seems normal.

On the second run (the one that is oddly slow) it seemed a bit different:
master used CPU almost all the time but not all of it (13% is max in my task manager and master continuously used from 5-8%) while workers CPU usage was on-and-off. I use 3 workers and while on the first run they all used 13% when they processed then here they fluctuated between not working at all (0%) to full capacity (13%) all meanwhile master was continuously using 5-8% of CPU.

I also set a browser just before my parLapply call and ran the serialize function manually on my data (with NULL as connection) and then it was almost instant (under a second).

Also, I tried the useXDR=FALSE switch but my program didn't complete even the first run when this was on (Set to FALSE). At third iteration in first run it just stopped processing and hung there indefinitely (master and workers took 0% of CPU).

I added an if block in my code to use lapply instead of parLapply on other runs after the first as Im completely out of ideas for now. This is just a workaround though and I'd still like to find the root of the problem

Again, many thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's hard to determine the problem with only profile data from the master, and it's very difficult to get profile data from the workers. However, this data does provide some clues.

The "serialize" function is used by the master to send task requests to the workers via a socket connection, and the "unserialize" function is used to retrieve the task results from the workers. It's normal and healthy for the master to spend a lot of time in "unserialize", since it normally has to block while waiting for the tasks to be computed (unless you've got the unhealthy situation of tiny tasks). But "serialize" should not block, since the master never sends a task to a worker unless it believes that the worker is ready and waiting for a task assignment.

So perhaps the workers are performing badly because they don't have enough memory or are experiencing networking problems, or the task data being sent to the workers is particularly difficult to serialize. I would use a process monitoring tool to try to determine which if one of these might be the problem. For example, if the master process is not using much CPU time, the problem is probably with the workers. If it is using a lot of CPU time, than the actual serialization of the data is probably the problem.

That being said, you may want to start by setting `useXDR=FALSE` when creating the cluster object:

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(detectCores(), useXDR=FALSE)
```

That may improve the performance of both "serialize" and "unserialize" significantly. Although "useXDR" defaults to `TRUE`, I believe XDR is only necessary when using both little and big-endian computers in one cluster, which isn't common.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I edited my original post with new info